# How to open a file from Excel according to the username

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a Word file from Excel using VBA. Right now I have this code:

```
Sub OpenWordFile_Odrebekræftelse()

    Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")

    Dim s As String
    On Error Resume Next
    s = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Indtaste brugernavn (initialer)", Type:=2)

    wordapp.documents.Open "C:\Users\" & s & "\Standarddokumenter\C02 Aftale\C02.5 Kontrakt\Ordrebekræftelse_version 1.1.dotx", ReadOnly:=True

    wordapp.Visible = True
```

This allow me to open the Word file by entering the user's initials when you push the button. The file's path is different according to who's the user and that's my problem here...

This method Works fine but I would like to get rid of the "enter your initials" part and have a macro that gets the username directly into the file's path according to who's session is in use... if you see what I mean.

Can anyone help me with that? I looked at the Getusername Things but couldn't get it to Work properly...

Thanks!

Edit: I don't want to display the username in a cell, I want to "insert" it in the path's file in the vba code (where " & s & " stands right now) ...if that makes any sense! :)

Comment: Side note: You should avoid `On Error Resume Next` this is bad practice. Please read [VBA Best Practices - Error Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5411/error-handling#t=201704210621116765052) to see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the environment variable `%USERPROFILE%` which relsults in `%SystemDrive%\Users\{username}`

In your case

```
wordapp.documents.Open "%USERPROFILE%\Standarddokumenter\C02 Aftale\C02.5 Kontrakt\Ordrebekræftelse_version 1.1.dotx", ReadOnly:=True
```

or

```
wordapp.documents.Open Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Standarddokumenter\C02 Aftale\C02.5 Kontrakt\Ordrebekræftelse_version 1.1.dotx", ReadOnly:=True
```

should work.

For more info see: [Wikipedia Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_values).

Comment: The second one Works well! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`s = Application.UserName` should do the trick.

`s = Environ("USERPROFILE")` might be even better.

Comment: Just a note: These two lines are not equal! The first results in something like `Prename I. Surname` (which in this case is not helpful at all because it returns the real name and not the Windows user name) and the second results in something like `C:\Users\username`.